# python/pandas - converting date and hour integers to datetime

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a dataframe that has a date column and an hour column.

```
     DATE         HOUR
  2015-1-1         1
  2015-1-1         2
      .            .
      .            .
      .            .
  2015-1-1         24
```

I want to convert these columns into a datetime format something like:
`2015-12-26 01:00:00`

Comment: I am not sure if this is useful since you are using a data frame, If reading off a csv, you can use: datetime.datetime.strptime("2015-1-1 01", "%Y-%m-%d %H") where you can combine the date and hour as string

Comment: @okkhoy I'll give this a try as well. The underlying source is from a csv so maybe before creating the final dataframe I can format the csv. Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could first convert `df.DATE` to datetime column and add `df.HOUR` delta via `timedelta64[h]`

```
In [10]: df
Out[10]:
       DATE  HOUR
0  2015-1-1     1
1  2015-1-1     2
2  2015-1-1    24

In [11]: pd.to_datetime(df.DATE) + df.HOUR.astype('timedelta64[h]')
Out[11]:
0   2015-01-01 01:00:00
1   2015-01-01 02:00:00
2   2015-01-02 00:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Or, use `pd.to_timedelta`

```
In [12]: pd.to_datetime(df.DATE) + pd.to_timedelta(df.HOUR, unit='h')
Out[12]:
0   2015-01-01 01:00:00
1   2015-01-01 02:00:00
2   2015-01-02 00:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```